# ERROR 1064 (42000) MYSQL. (No indentfiers, everything escaped with backticks

Tags: mysql

I just got this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`' at line 3

The answer on another question told me to use backticks -- which I already do.

This is what I was trying to run.

```
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, '', '', '', '')
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 6, 4839, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 1, 4832, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 6, 4840, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 1, 4833, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 6, 4841, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 6, 1276, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 1, 1271, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 6, 1277, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 1, 1272, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 6, 1278, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'armor', 2, 212, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'shield', 6, 825, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'shield', 1, 820, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'shield', 6, 826, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'shield', 1, 821, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'shield', 6, 827, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'pet', 6, 1624, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'pet', 1, 1623, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'pet', 6, 1625, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'pet', 1, 258, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'pet', 6, 1626, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'item', 6, 333, 1)
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'item', 6, 334, 1)
```

Why do I get the error? I escaped everything.

Comment: You need a `;` after each query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate between the `insert` statements with a `;`:

```
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, '', '', '', ''); -- Note the ;
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, 'weapon', 6, 4839, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert more queries, you should separate them using `;`, or better, end each one query by `;`.

```
INSERT INTO aq_db. `aq_shops` (`ShopId`, `ItemCategory`, `ShopBitmask`, `ItemId`, `Buyable`)
VALUES (133, '', '', '', '');
INSERT INTO ...
```